# How can I display DataFrame columns name on two lines?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset and I would like to have the column name displayed on two lines, instead of one.

What I have looks like this:

[image]

That I obtain setting column name in this way:

```
dff.columns=["Really intersting column name"]
```

I would like it to be like this

```
      Really intersting
      column name

0             2

0             9
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you use jupyter notebook?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Google Colab

Comment: Thanks in advance

Comment: It's easy to get what you want with Jupyter Notebook but I did not succeed with Google Colab :(. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone was wondering...

I was able to solve it this way, but it's very specific though:

```
dff.columns=["Really intersting column name"]
dff = dff.reset_index(drop=True)
dff.style.set_properties(subset=["Really intersting column name"], **{'width': '140px'})
```

I played around with the "width" properties and got this:

[image]

Comment: I had got this solution but you have to use each time you want to display your dataframe.

Comment: Since it was only for aesthetic reasons, i would say better than nothing